# How to put a timestamp on a video recorded by an app built on flutter

Tags: video, flutter, timestamp, recording

Is it possible to put a time stamp on a right bottom corner of the video in an application built with a help of flutter

Please, can someone give a hint how to do this

Comment: are you asking about adding a timestamp or widget positioning?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a stack widget to overlap timestamp which would be text widget aligned to topRight with the video widget.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this as follows

```dart
//get timestamp 
String date=DateTime.now().toUtc().toString();
  print(date);

Stack(children: <Widget>[
  Container(child:yourvideo),
   positioned(bottom:50,
   left:8,
  child:Text(date));
]);
```